# Question about modules, CMake and using modules in dll

Tags: c++, cmake, c++20

I've spend a lot of time trying to figure out an issue of compiling the solution for my studies using the cpp 20 modules in dynamic linked library. I've got my project structure as following:

```
- Main soluition directory
CMakeLists.txt
-- Application directory (sources for executable)
--- headers
.h files
--- resources
some resources for project
--- src
.cpp files
-- Library directory (some classes for project)
--- includes
.h files
--- interfaces
.ixx file (the module itself)
```

As you can see the solution contains two folders and I've got 1 Cmake file in parent folder to compile both exe and dll from there. Thing is - as if this would work with classic header includes, it doesn't with modules as the compilation order matters now as I learned. I'm just learning and the info on how to work with modules is scarce, I couldn't find how to order up my CMake lists to make this work pure via console.

Problem is that when running cmake to build the project - it won't find the dll's .o file and fails to building linking. The dll must be compiled up front somehow.

When I open the project in VS studio I'm able to build it if I order VS to build the .dll first and THEN order to build all. Then it successfully complies everything as the files from modules are supposedly built upfront and used later.

Did anyone had any experience on how to structure the CMake file, maybe with subfolder directives and separated CMake lists, to make it run properly?

I've got a CMakeLists.txt in parent directory like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.0)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

project(RaceGame)

include_directories(
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RaceApp/headers
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RaceApp/src
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RaceLib/interfaces        
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RaceLib/includes
)

link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RaceApp/interaces)

file(GLOB Lib_SRCS
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RaceLib/interfaces/*.ixx"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RaceLib/includes/*.h"
        )

file(GLOB App_SRCS
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RaceApp/headers/*.h"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RaceApp/src/*.cpp"
        )
        
configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RaceApp/resources/botnames.txt botnames.txt COPYONLY)
configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RaceApp/resources/botcallsigns.txt botcallsigns.txt COPYONLY)

add_library(RaceLib SHARED ${Lib_SRCS} "RaceLib/includes/RaceLibExceptions.h")
add_executable(RaceGame ${App_SRCS} "RaceLib/includes/RaceLibExceptions.h")

target_link_libraries(RaceGame RaceLib)
```

I've been trying many different ideas but I just have not enough experience with CMake to work this out.

--------------- EDITED

cmake command output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/JINX/DEVELOPMENT/CRaceGame/build
```

cmake --build command output

```
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/RaceLib.dir/RaceLib/interfaces/RaceLib.ixx.o
c++: warning: /home/JINX/DEVELOPMENT/RaceGame/RaceLib/interfaces/RaceLib.ixx: linker input file unused because linking not done
[ 40%] Linking CXX shared library libRaceLib.so
c++: error: CMakeFiles/RaceLib.dir/RaceLib/interfaces/RaceLib.ixx.o: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/RaceLib.dir/build.make:97: libRaceLib.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/RaceLib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

----------------------- EDIT 2

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.26")
    # 3.25
    set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "3c375311-a3c9-4396-a187-3227ef642046")
elseif (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.27")
    # 3.26
    set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "2182bf5c-ef0d-489a-91da-49dbc3090d2a")
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "See `https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v${CMAKE_VERSION}/Help/dev/experimental.rst`.")
endif (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.26")
# turn on the dynamic depends for ninja
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_DYNDEP ON)

project(RaceGame)

include_directories(
        RaceApp/headers
        RaceApp/src
        RaceLib/interfaces        
        RaceLib/includes
)

link_directories(RaceApp/interaces)

file(GLOB Lib_SRCS
        "RaceLib/interfaces/*.ixx"
        )

file(GLOB App_SRCS
        "RaceApp/src/*.cpp"
        )
        
configure_file(RaceApp/resources/botnames.txt botnames.txt COPYONLY)
configure_file(RaceApp/resources/botcallsigns.txt botcallsigns.txt COPYONLY)

add_library(RaceLib SHARED)

target_sources(
        RaceLib
        PRIVATE
        FILE_SET module_files
        TYPE CXX_MODULES
        BASE_DIRS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"
        FILES

        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RaceLib/interfaces/RaceLib.ixx
)

add_executable(RaceGame ${App_SRCS})

target_link_libraries(RaceGame RaceLib)
```

cmake command output

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.35.32215.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.35.32215.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Development/MS VS 2022 Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Development/MS VS 2022 Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:43 (target_sources):
  CMake's C++ module support is experimental.  It is meant only for
  experimentation and feedback to CMake developers.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done (7.6s)
CMake Warning (dev):
  C++20 modules support via CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_DYNDEP is
  experimental.  It is meant only for compiler developers to try.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Development/SOLUTIONS/RaceGame/build
```

cmake --build output:

```
MSBuild version 17.5.0+6f08c67f3 for .NET Framework

  Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule D:/Development/SOLUTIONS/RaceGame/CMakeLists.txt
  Scanning sources for module dependencies...
  RaceLib.ixx
  Compiling...
  RaceLib.ixx

... some my code warnings

Auto build dll exports
  Couldn't open file 'D:/Development/SOLUTIONS/RaceGame/build/RaceLib.dir/Debug/RaceLib.obj' with Crea
  teFile()

... errors
```

Comment: possibly useful to you: https://www.kitware.com/import-cmake-c20-modules/

Comment: yeah, it's a good topic I've been reading through as well. I've managed to compile projects with module inside it, but somehow I can't make it work if the module is in separate library.

thanks for comment.

Comment: Can you edit your question with full cmake output (from a clean source directory) and output of `cmake --build`? (or the full build log from VS, that is fine too)

Comment: Unrelated: `file(GLOB ...)` is an antipattern in CMake, and file paths are relative from the CMakeLists.txt in the source directory, so you do not need to add `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`. Finally, header files are automatically inferred as dependencies if included by source files (otherwise, what's the point?) so you do not need to add those either.

Comment: @Botje - yes, of cause, I've edited the post, thanks

Thanks for the unrelated info also, I'll try to use these advises )

Comment: It looks like CMake module support is [very much a work in progress](https://www.kitware.com/import-cmake-c20-modules/) and requires either a fork of GCC or a very recent MSVC. Suggest you read that and consider if it is worth your while. I do not think there is an alternative formulation that will prevent separate building.

Comment: @Botje that would be a shame, I've wanted to pull things in the latest fashion and getting blocked like this is quiet a sad outcome

Comment: @JINX Would you mind changing the `generator`? For example, replace it with `Ninja`, I rarely use `MS Build`, not quite sure where is the problem.

Comment: @Life4gal sorry, I seem to not fully understand how to do that, I've set set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "Ninja" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE), called the command few times for ninja to be used but it gave me some own errors instead, i'll try to figure out all that

Comment: I generally sort of sniffing out a problem source somewhere in around the fact that external module library can't 'see' it is being used and simply do not generate .lib file and thus linker can't link the library to the project coz it can't find the .lib file.

However it's still unclear for me how to make dll project with module to generate .lib file properly for the linker to use.

Comment: to set the generator, use [`-G`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-G) in the configure command. To get a list of generators, use `cmake --help`

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, to use the `module`, CMake version requirements are relatively high.

What you may need is [target_sources](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html#file-sets)

You can use:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.26")
    # 3.25
    set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "3c375311-a3c9-4396-a187-3227ef642046")
elseif (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.27")
    # 3.26
    set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "2182bf5c-ef0d-489a-91da-49dbc3090d2a")
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "See `https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v${CMAKE_VERSION}/Help/dev/experimental.rst`.")
endif (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.26")
# turn on the dynamic depends for ninja
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_DYNDEP ON)

add_library(my_module_library)

# MODULE SOURCE
target_sources(
        my_module_library
        PRIVATE
        FILE_SET module_files
        TYPE CXX_MODULES
        BASE_DIRS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"
        FILES

        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/my_module.ixx
)

# HEADER FILES
target_sources(
        my_module_library
        PUBLIC
        FILE_SET header_files
        TYPE HEADERS
        BASE_DIRS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src"
        FILES

        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/my_header.hpp
)
```

Comment: Thanks, how should I implement with with my project structure?

Comment: I've tried that and basically got same error:

Auto build dll exports
  Couldn't open file 'D:/Development/SOLUTIONS/RaceGame/build/RaceLib.dir/Debug/RaceLib.obj' with Crea
  teFile()

(went to windows with this to run latest cmake)

Comment: Would you mind posting your most recent version of CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: of cause, I've added the edit 2 to main post

Answer (score 1):

In the end I just switched the library to compile as STATIC library instead of SHARED. It works, tho. That's not what I wanted, but that's what I've got working.